# using jackson with module-info?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-modules

I can't for the life of me figure out how to include jackson in a java project using java modules.

I have tried a combination of using:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.module  
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype
com.faster.xml.jackson.core
```

nothing works...
errors range from:

```
module not found: com.fasterxml.jackson.module
```

and...

```
package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind is not visible
[ERROR]   (package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind is declared in the unnamed module, but module org.dshops.infobook does not read it
```

Does anyone have an example pom.xml/module-info.java that builds? or a pointer to one?

note this is where I started:

pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in module-info.java

```
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out myself.

In module-info.java: `requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;`

In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```